# javascript to let user to enter only single character

Tags: javascript, validation

I am weak in javascript so please help me for a javascript code that will allow user to enter only single character ie A,B,C,D,....,Z.But only a single character and also no numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
function fn()
{
    myString=document.getElementById("atext").value;
    patt=/[A-z]/g;
    x=patt.test(myString);
    alert(x);
}
</script>
<input type="text" id="atext" maxlength="1" />

<input type="button" id="btn" onclick="fn()" />
```

Answer (score 2):

This bit of JavaScript will test after every keystroke. If the key pressed is not a letter, it is removed. If it is a letter, it makes sure it is capitalized.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function validate(input){
    input.value = input.value.replace(/\W|\d/g, '').substr(0, 1).toUpperCase();
  }
</script>
<input id="input" type="text" onkeyup="validate(this);"/>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use html 5 pattern attribute.

```
<input type="text" pattern="[A-Za-z]{1}" title="Please enter only one letter"/>
```

Comment: maxlength isn't html5, it has been around for a looong time. OP is also looking to disallow numbers, so this wouldn't work.

Comment: hmm.actually i found the solution using maxlength.Just set the maxlength="1" and validate input to text only using javascript